# Addings elements to a list inside a dataframe columns in python from a database

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, dataframe

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["John",['a','b','c'],12], ["Smith",['c','x','z'],30]],
                 columns=['c1','c2','c3'])
```

And I have an sql table with different people and subjects they are interested in like `'a'` , `'b'` , `'z'` etc.. one person can have multiple interests obviously.

I want to know how is it possible in Python to actually make a `for` loop that table to add to my data-frame df all the interests for each person as an element in the list existing in the column `'c2'` exactly like the example? I couldn't find a proper way.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060158/how-to-append-an-element-to-a-list-inside-a-dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append an element to a List inside a DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060158/how-to-append-an-element-to-a-list-inside-a-dataframe)

Comment: You may be looking for the `apply` method of dataframes which allow you to call a function on dataframes as a whole

Comment: your dataframe is not valid, please edit it & add your expected output